# Swift Tests: Spying on `Encoder`?

Tags: swift, testing, mocking, xctest

I have some Swift models that encode data to json. For example:

```
struct ExampleModel: Encodable {
    var myComputedProperty: Bool { dependentModel.first(where: { $0.hasTrueProperty}) }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstKey = "first_key"
        case secondKey = "second_key"
        case myComputedProperty = "my_computed_property"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(firstKey, forKey: .firstKey)
        try container.encode(myComputedProperty, forKey: .myComputedProperty)
    }
}
```

The encoded data is sent to an API, and cross-platform system tests in this case are logistically tricky, so it's important I write tests that ensure the encoded data is as expected. All I'm looking to do is ensure `container.encode` receives expected keys and values.

I'm somewhat new to Swift, and trying to override the container, its dependencies & generics, and its .encode method is taking me down a rabbit-hole of rewriting half Swift's encoding foundation. In short: the spy I'm writing is too complex to be useful.

Despite lack of Google/StackOverflow results, I'm guessing spying on encoders is common (?), and that there's an easier way to confirm `container.encode` receives expected values. But the way swift's Encoder functionality is written is making it hard for me to do so without rewriting half the encoder. Anyone have boilerplate code or an example of effectively spying on `container.encode`?

Comment: Why to spy on the encoder? Isn't enough just to check that encoding result is equivalent  to the expected etalon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never done tests spying on encoder, although I have plenty of tests checking correction of encoding/decoding.

There are multiple ways to do it:

- You can get something like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and inspect encoded JSON
- You can use [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to mock sending a request to API, and examine the request the way it's sent (this allows to examine not only JSON, but headers as well)

But the most basic way to test is encoding *and then decoding* your data structure, and comparing the structures. They should be identical.

How it's done:

1. Create a `Decodable` extension for your `struct` (or if your `struct` is `Codable`, then you already ave this). It can be added directly in the test class / test target if you don't need it in the production code:

```
extension ExampleModel: Decodable {
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstKey = try container.decode(<...>.self, forKey: .firstKey)
        // etc
    }
}
```

2. Add `Equatable` extension for the `struct`:

```
extension ExampleModel: Equatable {
    // Rely on synthesized comparison, or create your own
}
```

3. Add a test:

```
let given = ExampleModel(firstKey: ..., ...)
let whenEncoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(given)
let whenDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(ExampleModel.self, from: whenEncoded)
// Then
XCTAssertEqual(given, whenDecoded)
```

Couple of notes:

- It's very unusual to encode computed property. It's not prohibited, but it breaks the immutability of the property you are about to send to API: what if it changes after you called `encode`, but before it was sent to API? Better solution is to make a `let` property in the struct, but have an option to create a struct with this value given with appropriate calculation (e.g. `init` for `ExampleModel` could be passing the `dependentModel`, and the property would be calculated in the init *once*)
- If you still choose to have a calculated property, you obviously cannot decode into it. So in that case you will need to preserve the decoded property in some class variable to compare it separately.

Comment: Many thanks @rapiddevice, this is really helpful. I was tempted to test by decoding, but at present my data is just `Encodable`, not `Codable`. The only reason to add decodable would be for testing purposes. I'm not completely averse to that, but is adding decodable just for testing a common strategy? Either way, many thanks.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you don't have to add `Decodable` to your production code if oyu don't need it, you can add it only to the test target (or even inside the test class as an extension. This is the simplest way to test the correctness of encoding, yes. But like I said, there are 2 other popular options: checking encoded JSON using some library, or checking the mocked HTTP request. Personally I usually invest into the mocked HTTP request _first_ because it serves 2 purposes at once (validates correctness of request, and headers), but for complicated encoding I'd use this method.

Comment: Ach - I misread about the production/test split. Many thanks!